# Do Isaiah 64:8-9 and Romans 11 indicate that the vessels of wrath have hope?

Tags: romans, isaiah

The imagery of a divine potter picking out some Jews to be hardened to the messiah and being reserved for destruction is for many of us unsettling. It is for many a kind of "fly in the ointment" that "makes the whole jar of perfume stink".

However, Paul, though he seems to be clinically depressed because of the imminent visitation that is going to come upon them in 70ad, seems to hold out some hope that the hardening will be lifted and the branches that were cut off would be grafted back in. I've highlighted several sections of this discussion where Paul seems to hold out hope:

> [Rom 11:7-34, 36 KJV] 7 What then? Israel hath not obtained that which he seeketh for; but the election hath obtained it, and the rest were blinded 8 (According as it is written, God hath given them the spirit of slumber, eyes that they should not see, and ears that they should not hear;) unto this day. 9 And David saith, Let their table be made a snare, and a trap, and a stumblingblock, and a recompence unto them: 10 Let their eyes be darkened, that they may not see, and bow down their back alway. 11 I say then, **Have they stumbled that they should fall? God forbid: but [rather] through their fall salvation [is come] unto the Gentiles, for to provoke them to jealousy. 12 Now if the fall of them [be] the riches of the world, and the diminishing of them the riches of the Gentiles; how much more their fulness?** 13 For I speak to you Gentiles, inasmuch as I am the apostle of the Gentiles, I magnify mine office: 14 **If by any means I may provoke to emulation [them which are] my flesh, and might save some of them. 15 For if the casting away of them [be] the reconciling of the world, what [shall] the receiving [of them be], but life from the dead?** 16 For if the firstfruit [be] holy, the lump [is] also [holy]: and **if the root [be] holy, so [are] the branches**. 17 And if some of the branches be broken off, and thou, being a wild olive tree, wert graffed in among them, and with them partakest of the root and fatness of the olive tree; 18 **Boast not against the branches. But if thou boast, thou bearest not the root, but the root thee.** 19 Thou wilt say then, The branches were broken off, that I might be graffed in. 20 Well; because of unbelief they were broken off, and thou standest by faith. Be not highminded, but fear: 21 For if God spared not the natural branches, [take heed] lest he also spare not thee. 22 Behold therefore the goodness and severity of God: on them which fell, severity; but toward thee, goodness, if thou continue in [his] goodness: otherwise thou also shalt be cut off. 23 **And they also, if they abide not still in unbelief, shall be graffed in: for God is able to graff them in again**. 24 For if thou wert cut out of the olive tree which is wild by nature, and wert graffed contrary to nature into a good olive tree: **how much more shall these, which be the natural [branches], be graffed into their own olive tree?** 25 For I would not, brethren, that ye should be ignorant of this mystery, lest ye should be wise in your own conceits; that blindness in part is happened to Israel, **until the fulness of the Gentiles be come in. 26 And so all Israel shall be saved**: as it is written, There shall come out of Sion the Deliverer, **and shall turn away ungodliness from Jacob: 27 For this [is] my covenant unto them, when I shall take away their sins. 28 As concerning the gospel, [they are] enemies for your sakes: but as touching the election, [they are] beloved for the fathers' sakes. 29 For the gifts and calling of God [are] without repentance. 30 For as ye in times past have not believed God, yet have now obtained mercy through their unbelief: 31 Even so have these also now not believed, that through your mercy they also may obtain mercy. 32 For God hath concluded them all in unbelief, that he might have mercy upon all.** 33 O the depth of the riches both of the wisdom and knowledge of God! how unsearchable [are] his judgments, and his ways past finding out! 34 For who hath known the mind of the Lord? or who hath been his counsellor? ... 36 For of him, and through him, and to him, [are] all things: to whom [be] glory for ever. Amen.

In Isaiah, in praying about the Jews being but clay in God's hands, he asks for God to "reign in his anger" and give the rejected clay hope and reminds him "we are all thy People":

> [Isa 64:8-9 KJV] 8 But now, O LORD, thou [art] our father; we [are] the clay, and thou our potter; and **we all [are] the work of thy hand**. 9 Be not wroth very sore, O LORD, neither remember iniquity for ever: behold, see, we beseech thee, **we [are] all thy people**.

It appears that Isaiah is affirming that both the vessels of mercy and the vessels of wrath are both "the work of God's hand" and "God's People".

So with all this hopeful talk about the vessels of wrath, might we be misunderstanding the finality of what it means to be a "vessel of wrath"? And if God has hardened these vessels how to they come to escape the hardness to get grafted back in?

Note: I've wondered why Paul's grief at the idea of divine hardening seems to give way to a doxology about God's wisdom and the brilliance of his plan to "have mercy on all".

What is the hope he is holding out?

Answer (score 1):

> <sup>1</sup>And you hath he quickened, who were dead in trespasses and sins 
>   <sup>2</sup>Wherein in time past ye walked according to the course of this world, according to the prince of the power of the air, the spirit that now worketh in the children of disobedience: <sup>3</sup>**Among whom also we all had our conversation in times past in the lusts of our flesh, fulfilling the desires of the flesh and of the mind; and were by nature the children of wrath, even as others.**
>   <sup>4</sup>But God, who is rich in mercy, for his great love wherewith he loved us, <sup>5</sup>Even when we were dead in sins, hath quickened us together with Christ, by ( grace ye are saved;)  <sup>6</sup>And hath raised us up together, and made us sit together in heavenly places in Christ Jesus: <sup>7</sup>That in the ages to come he might show the exceeding riches of his grace in his kindness toward us through Christ Jesus.
>   <sup>8</sup>For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God: <sup>9</sup>Not of works, lest any man should boast. <sup>10</sup>**For we are his workmanship, created in Christ Jesus unto good works, which God hath before ordained that we should walk in them.**
>   -- Ephesians 2:1-10 (KJV)

In verse 3, Paul states unambiguously, "*we **ALL** ... were by nature the children of wrath*", i.e. "WE were ALL vessels fit for destruction".

In verse 10, Paul states, "*we are his [God's] workmanship, created in Christ Jesus ...*", i.e. God added a good helping of Jesus Christ to the material fit for destruction in order to create new vessels.

Also it should be noted, the "good works" were fore-ordained, NOT those who should walk in them.

For those who get hung up on predestination:

> <sup>28</sup>And we know that all things work together for good to them that love God, to them who are the called according to his purpose.
>   <sup>29</sup>For whom he did foreknow, he also did predestinate to be conformed to the image of his Son, that he might be the firstborn among many brethren.
>   <sup>30</sup>Moreover whom he did predestinate, them he also called: and whom he called, them he also justified: and whom he justified, them he also glorified.
>   -- Romans 8:28-30 (KJV)

The sequence is:
      `Foreknowlege --> Predestination --> Calling --> Justification --> Glorification`

And the Predestination is specific: "*to be conformed to the image of his Son*", which is simply another way of saying:

> Being confident of this very thing, that **he which hath begun a good work in you will perform it until the day of Jesus Christ**:
>   -- Philippians 1:6 (KJV)

Those who step into the kingdom of God, through the gate Jesus has opened for them, will become vessels fit for glory, regardless of the quality of the material from which they were originally wrought.

Comment: How does a person selected by God to be hardened to the gospel (a "vessel appointed for wrath") then become a believer? Doesn't that suggest that the believer has overcome the divine hardening? IE: How would Pharaoh have ever relented since God hardened him? No miracle could influence him. But Paul seems to hold out that hope or something similar, no?

Comment: *Romans 11:5 Even so then at this present time also there is a remnant according to the election of grace.  It does not say that they are the vessels of wrath at all in 9:22 It says that he endured them with longsuffering to make known His riches to the vessels of mercy. He understood that a remnant would be saved, not all.

Comment: Why did God harden Pharaoh? Because God foreknew Pharaoh would never relent.  With every incident recorded in the narrative of the Bible, people will take the view that they prefer. I ask myself, "Do I prefer to believe that God fore-knew Pharaoh would never relent, so He used Pharaoh's inclinations to achieve His purposes?" OR "Do I prefer to believe that God caused Pharaoh to behave in evil ways counter to his inclinations to achieve His purposes?" Those who sympathise with Pharaoh's heart will prefer the latter, and those who sympathise with God's, the former.

Comment: A man will prefer to believe, what he prefers to be true.

Comment: @Ruminator I forget to add your tag in the previous comments.